# RSpec: how to set a controller's instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

I have a this method in my rails controller:

```
def some_init_func
  # ...
  @inst_var = 1
  # ...
end
```

and later on:

```
do_something_with(@inst_var)
```

How do I set this instance variable in RSpec?

```
allow(controller).to receive(:some_init_func) do
  # ???? what goes here ????
end
```

Comment: where does that variable come from?

Comment: have you tried `assign(:inst_var, 1)`?

Comment: @AbM I did try that. Getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'assign'`

Answer (score 5):

`assign` is an RSpec method available for view tests, but it's not supported for controller tests. Controllers are typically expected to *set* instance variables, so RSpec doesn't allow for setting them, but it does allow for checking them (i.e. via `assigns`).

To answer your question, though, Ruby has a `instance_variable_set` method available on all objects, which you can invoke from your controller test as follows:

`controller.instance_variable_set(:@inst_var, 1)`

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set for documentation, and note the tongue-in-cheek explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If `set_inst_variable` is a public method then simply call `controller.set_inst_variable`.

(It's usually preferrable to test through a class's public interface than alter its internal state).

Comment: This function is not really a "set_inst_variable" function. it's a general init function that does a lot of other things. Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question :)

Comment: My point remains that manipulating an object's internal state in order to test is generally a bad approach. It means your test will not reflect how the object is actually used in production code, so the tests become less effective. If you could post more of the controller's code then maybe could give more specific advice about how to test it.