# Controller test with RSPEC error does not implement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test my API controller with RSPEC. The action in controller have a service that I want to stub/mock. But I got error :

> Failure/Error: expect(Api::V1::PaymentsController).to
>   receive(:init_alias).and_return(svc)
>          Api::V1::PaymentsController does not implement: init_alias

Here my test :

```
  let(:alias_svc) { instance_double(AliasService) }

  describe 'POST /payment/card' do
    it 'returns urls (return, success, fail)' do
      expect(Api::V1::PaymentsController).to receive(:init_alias).and_return(alias_svc)
      expect(alias_svc).to receive(:insert)

      post '/payment/card'
    end
  end
```

And the controller :

```
module Api
  module V1
    class PaymentsController < ApiController
      before_action :init_alias, only: [:register_card]

      # POST /payment/card
      def register_card
          @url = @svc.insert current_user
      end

      private
      def init_alias
        @svc = AliasService.new
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**Edit :**

I tried to delete the first line (expect(Api::V1::PaymentsController).to receive(:init_alias).and_return(alias_svc)) but I got

> Failure/Error: expect(svc).to receive(:insert)
>        (InstanceDouble(AliasService) (anonymous)).insert(*(any args))
>          expected: 1 time with any arguments
>          received: 0 times with any arguments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Controller methods are instance methods. Therefore, `Api::V1::PaymentsController` does not implement `init_alias`.

RSpec allows to use `expect_any_instance_of`:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Api::V1::PaymentsController).to receive(:init_alias).and_return(alias_svc)
```

**Edit**

You send your message to `@svc`. Therefore, you should mock this instance variable to your controller.

You can do something like this:

```
let(:alias_svc) { instance_double(AliasService) }
controller.instance_variable_set(:@svc, alias_svc)
```

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579844/rspec-how-to-set-a-controllers-instance-variable).

Comment: it's almost working, thank you. But I still have the second error

Comment: Pass `alias_svc` into `instance_variable_set`. I've updated the answer.